# Java application directory structure

Tags: java, ruby, architecture, conventions, directory-structure

I'm new to Java (though a proficient Ruby programmer), and I'm looking to write a non-trivial Java application (with Swing).

What I've been unable to work out is how I should lay out my files, and how I should 'load' them. For example in a Ruby application I might have:

```
.
|-- application.rb
|-- includes
|   |-- chess
|   |   |-- bishop.rb
|   |   |-- castle.rb
|   |   |-- gameboard.rb
|   |   |-- horse.rb
|   |   |-- king.rb
|   |   |-- pawn.rb
|   |   |-- peice.rb
|   |   |-- player.rb
|   |   `-- queen.rb
|   |-- chess.rb
|   |-- house
|   |   |-- chimney.rb
|   |   |-- roof.rb
|   |   |-- wall.rb
|   |   `-- window.rb
|   `-- house.rb
`-- README.md
```

Now in Java I understand that there are packages to be handled instead of modules, and I probably need to get Ant's `build.xml` in there, etc. But I've yet to find a good guide to laying this all out.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [maven's Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Also if you are just now starting the project I will recommend using maven instead of Ant. It takes far less work to start a project with maven.

Comment: Thanks @ShaMan-H_Fel, what exactly goes in `src/main/resources` ? And how do you separate packages?

Comment: In resources you put any kind of external resources like images, and etc.
About the packages - here is a nice tutorial on the subject from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html It should answer all of your questions about how to handle packages in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a single `src` directory inside your project for your source code and, within it, directories laying out packages.

Outside this source directory you would have your build-related files.

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend to you that its very suitable if you use an IDE which you can get from here:

[Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) .

Because it is very useful if you want to build any project, you just have to select perspective and it will load for you some basic structure your application should have. And before IDE you should have JDK / JRE installed on your PC. I hope this help.

**EDIT :**  This seem to be your answer. [How to organize a Swing GUI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6269851/1134935)

**EDIT 2:** This is another link for your question and this helps me also: [general application directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540307/1134935)